# Distribution of sample variance: Chi-squared distribution problem

Tags: probability, statistics, chi-squared

I'm preparing for an exam and I can't seem to figure out the reasoning behind the answer to this question.

Why do they use a chi-squared test? Can someone walk me through their explanation? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires focus on some fussy (but important) details, so let me try to explain it step by step:

$$P(S_X^2 > 1.5\sigma^2) = P\left(\frac{S_X^2}{\sigma^2} > 1.5\right)
= P\left(Q =\frac{9S_X^2}{\sigma^2} > 9(1.5)\right)\\ = P(Q > 13.5) = 1-P(Q\le 13.5) = 0.1413 > 0.1,$$

where $Q \sim Chisq(df=9)$, and I have used R statistical software to get the exact probability, as shown below.

```
1 - pchisq(13.5, 9)  # in R 'pchisq' is the CDF of Chisq dist'n
## 0.1412558
```

I will leave it to you to look in your printed tables of the chi-squared
distribution to come as near as necessary to the exact value. [In my table: along the
row for df=9 and in the column for cutting 0.1 from the upper tail  of the
distribution, I find 14.6837. That is, $P(Q > 14.6837) = 0.1$ So $P(Q > 13.5)$ must exceed 0.1. Also, notice that subscripts in the headings of many distribution tables put the area in the *right tail* into the subscript (not the area to the left as for a CDF).
In my table the column mentioned above is headed $\chi_{0.100}^2.$]

Below is a plot of the $Chisq(9)$ PDF. The vertical red line is at 13.5;
the area under the curve to the right of this line is 0.1413. The dotted vertical green line is at 14.6837.

[image]

Now, I hope you can figure out the similar argument for $S_Y^2.$

Answer (score 0):

$\chi_n^2 = Z_1^2 + Z_2^2 \cdots + Z_n^2$

Where $Z_i$ are i.i.d standard normal random variables.  $n$ is the "degrees of freedom".  This is the definition.

So now, how do we estimate our spread parameters?  We calculate the mean squared error.  That is:

$s^2 = \frac 1{n-1} \sum_\limits{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar X)^2$

$s^2$ is an  estimate with uncertainty.  It is a random variable itself.  And what distribution describes our uncertainty in $s^2$

$X_i-\bar X$ are normally distributed random variables.

$\sum_\limits{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu)^2 = \sigma^2 \chi_n^2$

And we loose a degree of freedom from our estimate of $\bar X$

$\sum_\limits{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar X)^2 = \sigma^2 \chi_{n-1}^2$

Comment: I still don't understand where the P(X^2 > 1.5 * 9) > 0.1 came from. All I can think of is that 1.5 = 50% more than the true variance, and 9 is the degree of freedom. Looking at the table, 13.5 is less than the value of 14 which corresponds to alpha = 0.1 which doesn't make it > 0.1?